# Why are Kafka messages out of order when we only have a single partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafkajs

We're using [KafkaJS](https://kafka.js.org/) to send messages to a Kafka topic that is being consumed by a single consumer. Our Kafka instance is configured in `server.properties` to only have a single partition, and we can confirm the topic only has a single partition by looking at the output of `kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic <topic name>`. However, the messages being received by the consumer are out of order. How can this be the case given that our topic only has a single partition?

Comment: Have you checked what order the messages are in on the topic? you can use the kafka-console-consumer.sh for this.

Comment: Kafka will store the messages in the order it receives them in. Could it be possible that KafkaJS is not sending them in sequence? See if you can configure that and also configure acks to 1 or all (on KafkaJS) so that it waits for kafka to acknowledge that it's been written before producing the next message?

Comment: you may confirm the order/contents using any gui tools like Kafka topic viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here, but it turns out it wasn't an issue with Kafka itself.

The messages were being sent to Kafka inside of a `forEach` loop. Even though we were making sure to use `await` with each call to `send` on each iteration, [it turns out `forEach` doesn't play nice with asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394314/3987765). The fix was to use a traditional `for` loop.